# LogisticRegression complete quasi-separation

Tags: python, logistic-regression, propensity-score-matching

To compute propensity scores, I want to estimate cross-sectional binary response regression models on
a year-by-year basis using statsmodel LogisticRegression. As explanatory variables I consider firm characteristics, and the treatment group states if in the sample or not. The estimation results are confusing, suggesting possibly complete quasi-separation.

How can I address the poor model assessment metrics and the complete quasi-separation?

```
df = pd.read_excel("Posthoc/PSM_firms_combined.xlsx")
X_year = df[df['Year'] == 2015][['Total Assets', 'Growth', 'Price to Book Value per Share', 'Total Debt to Common Equity']]
y_year = df[df['Year'] == 2015]['Treatment']
logit_model = sm.Logit(y_year, X_year)
results = logit_model.fit()
print(results.summary())

# Obtain the chi-squared statistic
chi_squared = results.llr
print("Chi-Squared Statistic:", chi_squared)
# Calculate McFadden's R-squared
log_likelihood_model = results.llf  # Log-likelihood of the model
log_likelihood_null = results.llnull  # Log-likelihood of a null model
mcfadden_r2 = 1 - (log_likelihood_model / log_likelihood_null)
print("McFadden's R-squared:", mcfadden_r2)
# Obtain AUC-ROC
y_pred_prob = results.predict(X_year)
auc_roc = roc_auc_score(y_year, y_pred_prob)
print("AUC-ROC:", auc_roc)
```

[Logit Regression Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9bIA.png)

I tried without success `logit_model.fit(method = 'bfgs')` and the FirthLogisticRegression.

Comment: For propensity scores or predicting probabilities the non-identification of parameters is not really a problem. For any estimated parameters the predicted probabilities will be 0 or 1 (or close to them). However, for propensity score methods we need overlap of treated and untreated for ranges of x, which requires that probabilities have to stay far enough away from 0 and 1. (Often the recommendation is to drop observations with propensity score too close to 0 or 1.)

Comment: For the year 2015, 8 firms are in the treatment group. Most of their propensity scores range around e^-8, so close to 0. In the not-treatment group i am also having many observations close to 0. If i would drop observations in the non-treatment group close to 0, I would late have problems with the propensity score matching?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the propensity score matching literature. In inverse propensity weighting, observations with boundary probabilities cannot be included. In matching it may be that you just don't find ANY close enough match. But having to ignore 60% of the data might create a large selection effect. The (almost) surely treated and (almost) surely untreated will not have a corresponding individual/firm with the opposite treatment.

Comment: brief google search: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6714558/#:~:text=Propensity%20scores%20of%20zero%20or,be%20found%20for%20such%20subjects.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. With the current values, I am able to find close matches in the untreated group because in both groups there are many values close to 0. But due the magnitude of the propensity scores close to 0, I would assume that the mistake might be in the previous code of the logistic Regression or i did not consider for something? Because the model assessment metrics are poor.